# How to log all writes to php files with-in a specific directory?

Tags: linux, centos, web-server

Is there a way I can get my centos server to monitor my /home directory for any write requests to .php files and log the filename and timestamp of the write request?

I have a feeling i have someone poking around and just want to see if there are unauthorized writes happening.

Comment: if you are using centos, you can use auditd.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the syscheck functionality of OSSEC. Auditd is not scalable in my experience. If your server is underutilized auditd should work, but otherwise I'd suggest you tread carefully with it.

Answer (score 3):

using auditd, first thing you need to be sure the service auditd is running

```
service auditd status
auditd (pid  2973) is running...
```

now if you have many files, you can use find for write your audit rules.

```
find /home/ -type f -name '*.php' -exec auditctl -a exit,always -F path={} -F perm=rwa \;
```

Now you can try to access to one php file.

```
cat /home/file.php 
hello world
```

now you can use ausearch

```
ausearch -f /home/file.php
----
time->Fri Jul 10 18:11:43 2015
type=PATH msg=audit(1436479903.574:224): item=0 name="/home/file.php" inode=9469 dev=fd:00 mode=0100644 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 nametype=NORMAL
type=CWD msg=audit(1436479903.574:224):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1436479903.574:224): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7fff6a695805 a1=0 a2=7fff6a693710 a3=7fff6a693160 items=1 ppid=1636 pid=3299 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts1 ses=1 comm="cat" exe="/bin/cat" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
```

as you can seee in the above output, you have the following information, PID, PPID, SYSCALL NUMBER, COMM an so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could hash them. It's not a perfect solution, but you could run md5sum on each PHP file, then write that to a file. Then run it again a while later, write it to a file. You could run diff on the two md5sums and see which files have changed.

For doing recursive md5sum, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318530/generate-md5-checksum-for-all-files-in-a-directory).
For diff, [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff).

You could use find to list out each php file under a directory, take that list, and pass that list to each md5sum checks.

Keep in mind they may be able to modify this file, so take measures to ensure whoever you suspect can't just change the md5sum.

EDIT: Alternatively, a third party program like auditd.

EDIT again: You don't even need diff, md5sum -c

Answer (score 0):

I felt this was worth another answer rather than an edit.

Similar to what my answer was, here's an actual implementation.
http://pastebin.com/jXPAL8dS

Save the script, make it executable, and
run:

```
mkdir /md5s && ./md5chk
```

Then run ./md5chk with a cron job or something. If you have it run in the background, consider having it pipe to wall or write to a logfile (just ./md5chk >> /var/log/md5s.log) to provide proper alerts. Add a line at the top simply saying

```
date
```

to get the time of execution.

Some may see this as re-inventing the wheel, but

1. I like this output better
2. auditd = another dependency for your system, whereas md5sum is possibly pre-installed